# Application not working and I dont know the reason

Tags: android

I have below code and once I run application it is crashed, I dont know the reason sorry Iam new on android so any one can help me

```
RecyclerView recyclerView;
    Button btn;
    Context context;
    ImageView imageView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.a);
        TextView textView=findViewById(R.id.txt);
        textView.setText(getString(R.string.action_settings));
        imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

            }
        });
```

Comment: show your error log and show your layout xml

Comment: your `imageView` is null. You need to bind it with `findViewById`. Same like you did for textView.

Comment: oh yeah Imageview is null

Comment: https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/am-logcat check this and next time posting question,please post the error too

Comment: @HanaWillian may i know reason why you changed your accepted answer?? As i helped you first here with clear ideas. I just want to know reason!! thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you forgot to define your image view before adding on click listener, please try below code if it is not working please share your xml file

```
 RecyclerView recyclerView;
        Button btn;
        Context context;
        ImageView imageView;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.a);
            TextView textView=findViewById(R.id.txt);
            imageView=findViewById(R.id.imageView);      
            textView.setText(getString(R.string.action_settings));
            imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {

                }
            });
```

Answer (score 1):

your `imageView` is null. You need to bind it with `findViewById`. Same like you did for `textView`

```
 imageView=findViewById(R.id.img);
 imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

            }
        });
```